# Why do i have a multi-second delay in booting linux under vmware fusion?

Tags: linux, vmware

When booting Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux 3.13.0) under VMWare Fusion 7.1.0, booting is slower than i'd expect. In particular, once it has completed, looking at the timestamps in `dmesg` show some long pauses (2+ seconds) adjacent to messages about `ACPI`. How can i make it less slow? Is it doing anything in those pauses that i don't need and can disable/hint?

Here's the first pause (`===>` ~5s), and just before it, a mini-pause (`--->` ~600ms):

```
[    0.145333] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.145335] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.145489] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] (base 0xf0000000)
[    0.145490] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] reserved in E820
[    0.151776] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.153045] bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
[    0.154170] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.154172] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.154173] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.154173] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.163605] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
---> 0.762966] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.762980] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[    0.762985] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S3_] (20131115/hwxface-580)
[    0.762994] ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S4 S5)
[    0.762996] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.763031] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.778294] ACPI: No dock devices found.
===> 5.789452] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-7f])
[    5.789463] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI]
[    5.789741] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: platform does not support [AER]
[    5.789996] acpi PNP0A03:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME PCIeCapability]
```

Here's the next pause (`===>` ~2.5s):

```
[    5.880797] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 *9 10 11 14 15)
[    5.880852] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 *11 14 15)
[    5.880904] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 7 9 *10 11 14 15)
[    5.880956] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 *5 6 7 9 10 11 14 15)
===> 8.417603] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 0F
[    8.417615] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0: notify handler is installed
[    8.418094] Found 1 acpi root devices
[    8.418615] vgaarb: device added: PCI:0000:00:0f.0,decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
```

And the next (`==>` ~2.1s), apparently *after* scanning for devices:

```
[    8.468367] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
[    8.468505] system 00:0a: [io  0xfce0-0xfcff] has been reserved
[    8.468507] system 00:0a: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] has been reserved
[    8.468508] system 00:0a: [mem 0xfe800000-0xfe9fffff] has been reserved
[    8.468510] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
==> 10.526525] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [on the Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_in_VMware#Slow_boot_time), this appears to relate to the support for hot-adding memory to a running machine. If you don't need this (and i didn't), you can disable it with the following line in your `.vmx` file (there is probably already a `"TRUE"` in there; change it to `"FALSE"`).

```
mem.hotadd = "FALSE"
```

This shaved 10 seconds off my boot time, bringing me down to a total of 10 seconds from the bootloader launching ubuntu to the graphical unity desktop being ready (with my user auto-logged-in). Here, you can see the message after that last delay above (`===>`) happens under the 1-second mark!

```
[    0.945859] pnp 00:09: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0700 (active)
[    0.945996] system 00:0a: [io  0xfce0-0xfcff] has been reserved
[    0.945998] system 00:0a: [mem 0xf0000000-0xf7ffffff] has been reserved
[    0.946000] system 00:0a: [mem 0xfe800000-0xfe9fffff] has been reserved
[    0.946001] system 00:0a: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c02 (active)
===> 0.948847] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 11 devices
```